# If $\phi \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is sufficiently nice, then $\exists f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that its Fourier transform is $\phi$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

If $\forall\ g \in \{\phi, \phi', \phi''\}$, $g \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} g(x) = 0$ then $\exists\ f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\hat{f} = \phi$.

I could only think of using the inverse tranform for functions in $L^2$ (integrating against $e^{2\pi i xy}$)  and check if that works, but I couldn't get to anything.

I also tried applying Integration by Parts to $\int \phi'' e^{2\pi i xy}$ or something similar so that I could use the properties above, but with no such luck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: So you are trying to find a class of functions where the inverse fourier transform is defined?

Comment: No, I already know about the distribution space :). I want to prove that the inverse is in $L^1$